# pub get to install non-dart dependancies similar to NPM, pip, etc?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

When looking at the pub spec format, i was curious if I can install other packages with pub get.  My goal is to either install Ruby or some other tools.  Even if i have command line access I could run python scripts or similar to get the code.

How does the dart package manager work in this sense?  Would it be simpler to just wrap dart with npm or similar and then do all the installs in NPM and follow it up with pub get?

I am curious what the rest of the community is doing for non-dart dependency injection.

Part of me was thinking the *executables* flag, but i was not not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for this.

I have a command line tool called `scripts` that you can use to run additional commands, but it's not an official Dart tool or anything.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scripts

Comment: yeah, I am similar.  I write CLI tools in python to manage environment personally, but i was hoping there was a built in tool to accomplish this.  Maybe this could be a solid enhancement to the pubspec file?  I think so.